# How to prove that composition of two $C^\infty$ fuctions is a $C^\infty$ function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, partial-derivative

Let $U, V$ be open subsets of $\Bbb R^{n}$ and $\Bbb R^m$ respectively such that $f:U \to V$ is a $C^\infty$ function. If $g:V \to \Bbb R^p$ is also a $C^\infty$ function, how do I show that the composite $g \circ f:U \to \Bbb R^p$ is also a $C^\infty$ function?

My progress: Since $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function, all partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ exist on $U$ and are continuous and hence $f$ is differentiable on $U$. Similarly, $g$ is also differentiable on $V$ and thus using the chain rule we find that $g \circ f$ is also differentiable on $U$. Thus, $\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x_j} = D_{e_j}(g \circ f)$, the directional derivative along $e_j$ exists.

I can't even see why $\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x_j}$ has to be continuous. Now to show that $g \circ f$ is a $C^\infty$ function, we have to show that all partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^k (g \circ f)}{\partial x_{i_1}\partial x_{i_2}\cdots\partial x_{i_k}}$ exist and are continuous. I think I have to use induction but I can't see how I can use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AhmedHussein my definition of $C^k$ is "all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous". I'm afraid I don't know any other equivalent definition. And pardon me my ignorance, but if $f: U(\subset \Bbb R^n) \to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable on $U$, then isn't $f'$ a function from $U \to Hom(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)$. Then how does $f''$ make sense?

Comment: @AhmedHussein, okay then, how do I use the other definition to solve my initial question?

Comment: Have you tried the chain rule?

Comment: @JohnM, the chain rule is only for total derivatives right? I don't know if there is any chain rule on partial derivatives. Apart from what I've written in the question, I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion over derivatives in multiple variables.  I hope the below clarifies the situation:

Let $f: U \rightarrow V$ be a $C^1$ map, where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.  Then in the standard basis we can view the derivative $Df$ of $f$ as the $m \times n$ Jacobian matrix:
$$Df = \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$$
Since $f$ is $C^1$, all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous.  At each point $x \in U$, $Df(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Similarly, if $g: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a $C^1$ map, then we can write
$$Dg = \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial y_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial y_m}\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \dfrac{\partial g_p}{\partial y_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial g_p}{\partial y_m} \end{bmatrix}$$
where again the partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

Then by the **chain rule**, the derivative $D(g \circ f)$ of the composition $g \circ f$ of $f$ and $g$ is:
$$D(g \circ f) = Dg \cdot Df,$$
which at means at each point $x \in U$ that
$$D(g \circ f)(x) = Dg(y) \cdot Df(x),$$
where $y = f(x)$.
In the standard basis you can view the above as the multiplication of matrices.  In summation notation, we can write the partial derivative of $g \circ f$ as
$$\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i = 1}^m \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_i}\circ f\right) \cdot \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}.$$

A moment's thought should convince you that the matrix entries of derivative of $D(g \circ f) = Dg \cdot Df$ in the standard basis exist and are continuous, and therefore $g \circ f$ is $C^1$.  In particular, $\partial(g \circ f)/\partial x_j$ is continuous for $j=1,\dots,n$, which at least answers your most basic question.

Now can you finish the argument that if $f$ and $g$ are $C^\infty$, so is $g \circ f$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i = 1}^m \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y_i} \circ f \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$?

Comment: Yes that's probably a better way to write it.